# ¿Es correcto utilizar dos verbos en subjuntivo imperfecto de forma consecutiva?

Tags: subjuntivo

Hace poco me topé con la siguiente oración:

"En dicho contrato se consignó su estado civil como casado en segundas nupcias, tal como él lo **declarara** ante el escribano que **certificara** el contrato."

Tal como está escrita, esta oración suena muy mal, al menos en mi opinión, pero no estoy seguro de si esto se debe a que los verbos en subjuntivo imperfecto riman o a que existe una regla gramatical que desaconseja el uso de dos verbos en subjuntivo imperfecto de forma consecutiva.

En mi opinión, hubiese sido mucho más natural escribir:

"En dicho contrato se consignó su estado civil como casado en segundas nupcias, tal como él lo **declarara** en su momento ante el escribano que **certificó** el contrato."

Gracias.

Comment: Deberías proporcionar la oración completa. Lo que has escrito es una subordinada y, sin la proposición principal, resulta difícil determinar si los tiempos verbales son correctos o no.

Comment: En su momento, él lo declarará ante el escribano que certificó el contrato. En su momento, él declarará (algo), ante el escribano que certificó el contrato.

Comment: @Gustavson Modifiqué la pregunta para incluir la oración completa.

Comment: @Diego, me temo que tal vez el corrector automático haya cambiado las conjugaciones verbales. Podrías por favor darle una mirada a la pregunta tal cual aparece ahora?

Comment: - En dicho contrato, su estado civil se consignó como casado en segundas nupcias, tal como lo declarará ante el escribano que lo certificó. - Mejor - En dicho contrato, su estado civil se registro como casado en segundas nupcias, tal como lo manifestará  ante el mismo escribano que lo certificó.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En sentido estricto, la oración:

- "En dicho contrato se consignó su estado civil como casado en segundas nupcias, tal como él lo **declarara** ante el escribano que **certificara** el contrato."

es correcta. "Declarara" y "certificara" son formas del pretérito imperfecto del subjuntivo equivalentes al pretérito perfecto simple o al pluscuamperfecto del modo indicativo:

- "En dicho contrato se consignó su estado civil como casado en segundas nupcias, tal como él lo **declaró** ante el escribano que **certificó** el contrato."
- "En dicho contrato se consignó su estado civil como casado en segundas nupcias, tal como él lo **había declarado** ante el escribano que **certificó** el contrato."

(El pluscuamperfecto se justifica porque la declaración precedió a la certificación.)

En la Nueva Gramática de la Lengua Española, la RAE dice en 24.1.2e que este uso del pretérito imperfecto del subjuntivo es frecuente en la lengua literaria, y más aún en la periodística y la ensayística.

El hecho de usar "declarara" y "certificara" puede ser, a mi entender, estilísticamente objetable por su cacofonía y semánticamente criticable porque se utiliza el mismo tiempo verbal para referirse a dos momentos diferentes, la declaración y la certificación. "Declarara" es anterior a "certificara". Nótese que, sin dejar de ser cacofónica, esta otra oración suena levemente mejor:

- "En dicho contrato se consignó su estado civil como casado en segundas nupcias, tal como él lo declarara ante el escribano y afirmara ante los testigos." (La declaración y la afirmación fueron simultáneas o inmediatas: tal como él lo había declarado ante el escribano y afirmado ante los testigos, tal como él lo declaró ante el escribano y afirmó ante los testigos.)